# How to insert input values to email body via php

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I am developing a website and I can't get through this simple step:
Simply how to insert input values of order form to email body of the message I send via php code.

Finally it works. I just randomly changed the code until success. Here it is:

**HTML code:**

```
"<form name="order" method="post" action="email_script.php">
 <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше Имя">
 <input type="text" name="telephone" placeholder="Ваш Телефон">
 <input type="submit" value="ОСТАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ">
 </form>"
```

**PHP code:**

```
$message .= $_POST["name"];
$message .= $_POST["telephone"];
$message = wordwrap($message,70);
mail("nsaann@gmail.com","Заказ",$message);
```

What should I write instead of

```
$message .= "$_POST['name']\n";
$message .= "$_POST['telephone']"\n";
```

in order to fix the issue?

**Exception stacktrace:**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE),
expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number 
(T_NUM_STRING) in /home4/nsaann/public_html/xparen.com/email_script.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change here

```
"<form name='order' method='post' action='email_script.php'>
  <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Ваше Имя'>
  <input type='text' name='telephone' placeholder='Ваш Телефон'>
  <input type='submit' value='ОСТАВИТЬ ЗАЯВКУ'>
</form>"
```

Also change here

```
$message = "";
$message .= "$_POST['name']\n";
$message .= "$_POST['telephone']\n";
```

Comment: @NazarSerdyuk You can make one ans as resolved your problem, by clicking on right tick mark below upvote/downvote.

Comment: It is still not working - here is the message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home4/nsaann/public_html/xparen.com/email_script.php on line 3

Comment: What is not working ? in your php file try with blank assignment\ `$message = "";`

Comment: That works, I have already tried that. The problem is specifically to assign values from the form

Comment: @NazarSerdyuk , what was the problem ans what worked for you now ;)

Comment: I have no clue what why it didn't worked. I just randomly changed the script until it started to work. The final script is in the first post

Answer (score 0):

After you append $_POST fields to $message, you overwrite this variable with wordwrap($msg,70), and I'm gonna guess that $msg doesn't exist. You probably wanna use $message there instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that